# Should schema validation shortcuts be allowed with strings?

Tags: karate

I recently had a 1 off test that had 2 strings as an optional response value, but when trying to match with the '##' shortcuts, it failed.   Followed the insight found [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions)

match in test

```
    * match $.txnId == txnIdCheck
    * match $.timestamp == timestampCheck
    * match $.message == '##("SUCCESS")'
    * match $.code == '##("An error occurred while processing hotlisted status")'
    * match $.hotListedStatus == '#boolean'
```

response

```
{
  "txnId": "b4415a7a-ced3-4553-92a5-bc0c8eafc388",
  "timestamp": "2024-01-05T18:40:40.248Z",
  "code": "An error occurred while processing hotlisted status",
  "hotListedStatus": false
}
```

Error

```
* match $.message == '##("SUCCESS")'
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | actual path does not exist (STRING:STRING)
  '#notpresent'
  'SUCCESS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Karate is designed to work like this:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "txnId": "b4415a7a-ced3-4553-92a5-bc0c8eafc388",
  "timestamp": "2024-01-05T18:40:40.248Z",
  "code": "An error occurred while processing hotlisted status",
  "hotListedStatus": false
}
"""
* match response == 
"""
{
  "txnId": "#string",
  "timestamp": "#string",
  "message": "##string",
  "code": "#string",
  "hotListedStatus": "#boolean"
}
"""
```

This also works:

```
* def expected = 
"""
({
  "txnId": "#string",
  "timestamp": "#string",
  "message": "##('foo')",
  "code": "#string",
  "hotListedStatus": "#boolean"
})
"""
* match response == expected
```

Comment: did as recommended by setting the response in a code bracket, but even though a field is marked with 2 #, it is still being evaluated. `* match response ==
    """
    {
      txnId : '#(txnIdCheck)',
      timestamp : '#(timestampCheck)',
      message : "##('SUCCESS')",
      code : "##('An error occurred while processing hotlisted status')",
      hotListedStatus : '#boolean'
    }
    """` results in the following

Comment: `match failed: EQUALS$ | not equal | actual does not contain key - 'message'(MAP:MAP)
{"txnId":"2b66e289-c572-4dd3-928d-b0054f74e94e","timestamp":"2024-01-08T17:08:53.905Z","code":"An error occurred while processing hotlisted status","hotListedStatus":false}
{"txnId":"#regex[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}","timestamp":"#regex^[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]{1}T[0-2][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1}(\\.[0-9]{1,9})?(Z)?(-[0-2][0-9]{1}:[0-5][0-9]{1})?$","code":"An error occurred while processing hotlisted status","hotListedStatus":"#boolean","message":"SUCCESS"}`

Comment: also tried with the quotes in a different order and received same response - `message : '##("SUCCESS")',
      code : '##("An error occurred while processing hotlisted status")',`

Comment: [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas) - thoughts?  Do you see an issue with the above, or is this a new bug?

Comment: it appears as though the ()'s around the response object is necessary, when using the string value in the validation.`* match response ==
    """
    ({
      txnId : '#(txnIdCheck)',
      timestamp : '#(timestampCheck)',
      message : '##("SUCCESS")',
      code : '##("An error occurred while processing quarantined status")',
      quarantineStatus : '#boolean'
    })
    """`.  Is this by design, when the second # is used to make a field optional as the examples I referenced do not use the ()'s - `* def foo = { bar: '#("hello " + name)' }` and `* match foo == '#("a" + 1)'`